# Multiple search results from a search within a single file

Tags: php, jquery, sql, search

I am trying to set up a search that is giving me multiple results from a search within a single html file. Let's assume the html contains the following extract:

```
<input id="search" type="text">
<div class="chapter" id="chap1">
    <h1>Chapter 1 - Introduction</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="chapter" id="chap2">
    <h1>Chapter 2 - Say hello</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum. Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="chapter" id="chap3">
    <h1>Chapter 3 - Say bye</h1>
    <p>Ipsum Ipsum. Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

If I would now search for "Lorem", I want to get a result for every div of the class "chapter" that contains "Lorem" (= the first and the second div = 2 search results). Every search result should be only a link that has the content of h1 and goes to the respective div, when it is clicked.

Example:

```
<p>Your search has returned 2 results.</p>

<a>Chapter 1 - Introduction</a>

<a>Chapter 2 - Say hello</a>
```

Ideally, the original content then should not be displayed until I remove the search text or click on one of the results.

Thank you very much! Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: create links in your javascript function that have an href="#chap1" (or any other ID you want to associate with it). I would suggest using jQuery for this because you can use CSS selectors to navigate pretty easily. *https://beski.wordpress.com/2009/04/21/scroll-effect-with-local-anchors-jquery/*

Comment: Where are the links in your sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/878dkrd9/

```
$(function(){

    $('#search').keyup(function(){
        var searchText = $('input#search').val();
        if(searchText.length > 0){
            $('div.chapter:contains(' + searchText + ')').show();
            $('div.chapter:not(:contains(' + searchText + '))').hide();
        }else{
            $('div.chapter').show();
        }
    });

    // Required to make the jQuery contains NON-Case-sensitive
    jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
      return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
          .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };

    // OVERWRITES old selecor
    jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
      return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
          .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks Gregg, this is getting close, but what I need is the results with the text of h1 only and as a link so that when clicking it, I navigate to the chapter and the whole content is restored.

Answer (score 1):

After a few tries I have now exactly what I want (even though the code might not be 100% well written). :)

Thank you Gregg!

This is the link to the final result:

```
$(function(){

$('#search').keyup(function(){
    var searchText = $('input#search').val();
    if(searchText.length > 0){
        $('div.chapter:contains(' + searchText + ')').show();           
        $('div.chapter:not(:contains(' + searchText + '))').hide();
        $('p.weg').hide();
        $('a').addClass("blue");
        $('pre').addClass("show");            
    }else{
        $('div.chapter').show();  
        $('p.weg').show();
        $('a').removeClass("blue");
        $('pre').removeClass("show");            
    }
});
```

...

https://jsfiddle.net/878dkrd9/106/